# Laravel rest api nested request

Tags: laravel, rest, api, nested

I'm writing rest apis in Laravel. Everything is ok when the request parameters are not nested. I can get any input parameters by `->`. e.g.

```
$model->update([
    'column' => $request->value,
]);
```

However if I'd like the parameters to have nested structure, what is the way to get them? `$request->value->nested_value` doesn't work as the `value` is not an object.

Example of nested request parameters:

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "name": "game9",
        "images": {
            "icon_id": 1,
            "banner_id": 1,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share example of your request

Answer (score 1):

When you get the values from the request, they are not `objects`. They are `arrays`.

You need to access them like this:

`$request->value['nested_value']`

Comment: You're right but the problem is where the value is not required in the request and if the user did not set the value, an error occurs saying undefined index 'nested_value'. Is there another way to overcome such a problem?

Comment: @MohammadrezaSahelgozin You have to add a Validation the request before you use the data, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation, this link show how you can achieve that.